# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0 when using Atlassian.SDK 10.6.0

Tags: json.net, fusion

My project is using Nuget package Atlassian.SDK 10.6.0.
When calling

```
var jc = Atlassian.Jira.Jira.CreateRestClient(_jiraBaseUrl, _jiraApiUsername, _jiraApiPassword);
```

I have the error

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

My web.config already has the bindingRedirect

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
```

I also checked the fusion log

> ```
> Calling assembly : Atlassian.Jira, Version=10.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
> ===
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
> LOG: Using application configuration file: F:\Titan\AutoLedgers\Facade\web.config
> LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
> LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
> LOG: Post-policy reference: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
> LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
> ```
>
> ASP.NET Files/facade/a6115f90/89f913a7/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files/facade/a6115f90/89f913a7/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/Titan/AutoLedgers/Facade/bin/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
>       LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: F:\Titan\AutoLedgers\Facade\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>       LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
>       LOG: Assembly Name is: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
>       WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
>       ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
>       ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131040.
>       ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

I really have no idea how can I resolve this issue now. Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

A few years too late, but I came across this question when searching for an answer to the same problem.  In my case I was building a .Net 4.8 Framework Windows Application with a dependency on the Atlassian.SDK 13.0.0 and Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.3 NuGet packages.  The solution was to ensure that the app.config was being copied alongside the built executable.

I had a postbuild step that was copying the built *.exe and dependencies to a deployment folder but it wasn't copying the app.config.

For reference my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```